# #1064 Error when importing Wordpress DB into PHPMyAdmin on WAMP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to import the production database of a Wordpress site into PHPmyAdmin to create a local copy of the production server. This database was exported from the RDS on AWS. However, when I try to import I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:4:{s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:3:\"rss\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:' at line 1
```

Below is the section of the file referenced by the error:

```
(1642,'_transient_feed_ac0b00fe65abe10e0c5b588f3ed8c7ca',**'a:4:{s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:3:\"rss\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s**:3:\"\n\n\n\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"version\";s:3:\"2.0\";}}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"channel\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:49:\"\n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n  \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:4:{s:0:\"\";a:7:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:14:\"WordPress News\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:26:\"https://wordpress.org/news\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:14:\"WordPress News\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:13:\"lastBuildDate\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:31:\"Tue, 16 Aug 2016 19:54:28 +0000\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}
```

Below is the start of the file that was exported from AWS:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.46, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com    Database: xxxx
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.27-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Would this kind of export just not be compatible with PHPMyAdmin? Is there anything I can fix in the file to allow it to be imported?

Comment: Is the database name same on phpmyadmin as it was on RDS?

Comment: No it isn't. Trying that now

Comment: Change this Database: xxxx to the name what it is on phpmyadmin and then try to import. Also what is the MYSQL version of your local DB phpmyadmin?

Comment: Darn! Same error still.

Comment: Show us the sql statement referenced in the error message pls.

Comment: It says the error's at line 1.  Usually, that'd make me suspect your line endings aren't correct for the server you're importing into (say you're trying to import a file with Unix endings into a Windows server).  If you convert the file to have the right endings (your text editor may be able to do that for you), does it work?

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin front end to import or command line?

Comment: @error2007s I'm using the front end.

Comment: @Hobo Good call. Checking that out now

Comment: Or just all previous rows are commented out...